# Why is $\exp(-i\pi x)$ not equal to $(-1)^x$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

I am not sure as to why $\exp(-i \pi x)$ not equal to $( \exp(-i \pi) )^x= (-1)^x$ .

Comment: This is only false if $x\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: How do you define $(-1)^x$ here?

Comment: What is $x$ ? A real number ? A complex number ?

Answer (score 3):

The "normal" laws of exponents, as they apply to *real numbers* and *real exponents*, do not always hold with complex-valued exponents. So we can't necessarily apply the law $a^{bc} = \left(a^b\right)^c$ unless we know $b, c\in \mathbb R$.